# After AJAX call specific button via jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get this to work for a while now and dug around, but so far have found no solution.

**CASE**

I have a tree-view in which I can click on an item within that tree-view to load data in a couple of tab-panes. This works fine via AJAX.

Other options, like changing data within the input files and automatically saving (using pretty much an `onkeyup` at the inputs) works fine too, no problem here.

One of my tab-panes has a sidebar with a button, in which I want users to assign a profile to this data. The jQuery is as following:

```
$('#profiles').on("click", ".content-container", function(e, data) { 

    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log('i got hit in the face');
    
});
```

This is in my `main.js` file.

The rest of my 2000 lines work fine, so it isn't the JS file or the opening of jQuery.

The `.content-container` is the static item in which I load my pane controls where, within, the underlying HTML has been placed.

```
<div class="menu-section active">
    <ul class="nav side-menu">
         <li class="">
             <a href="http://localhost/etim" id="profiles" class="">
                 <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece "></i>
             </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the sake of argument, this is the most basic I'll put down the button. You click on a href in that sidebar, and it should simply give me a `console.log` back.

However, every time it refreshes the page since my href is being automatically filled with my standard URL (no # but a reference to localhost), hence the `e.preventDefault`. When I click on this button it fails to prevent the default action and reloads the page anyway.

I thought I did everything right by assigning it to the `.on` since I know it will be placed later in the code, but apparently it still doesn't see it in my code.

Comment: Close.  But just using `.on()` isn't a magic wand.  The key is that `$('#profiles')` finds nothing when it executes, since that element is added to the page later.  Bind to an ancestor element that exists at the time of the binding, and use `#profiles` in the selector passed to `.on()`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize i had to swap those two arround, that i had to look within the static item for that item. I thought i had to use the id and interpreted the second value within the `.on()` function as the static item i had to look in